# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider::addField()

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, listing

I'm trying to populate a grid with data from DB. I've looked at other examples, tried appending `_listing` to the xml that renders the grid, tried just about everything I can think of and still can't get it to work.

*The full error I get is*:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider::addField() in Magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php on line 116**

`Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->addFieldToSelect( )` calls `addField()` which is not defined. Even if I define it (by extending AbstractDataProvider if I recall right) `$this->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect($field, $alias);` throws an error. Because it can't get the collection. It's null. But digging and tinkering through the source code is of no use. I must've missed something and I have no idea what it might be.

I've seen modules with custom DataProvider classes, i.e. `di.xml` has nothing to do with the `dataSource` defined in the listing XML. I've tried that as well but without luck.

This is my grid(or listing, if you prefer) - **so_grid.xml**:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">listing_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Item</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<!-- Data Source -->
<dataSource name="so_grid_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">TestDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">so_grid_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">request_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <!-- Filters -->
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <!-- Paging -->
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</listingToolbar>
<!-- Columns -->
<columns name="listing_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </item>
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

I have a working routing; the `InstallSchema` ran fine; there's a model, `resourceModel` and a `collection`. Let me know if I you need me to provide the code for any of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working! It turned out I was missing a lot of things(__constructors, *di* config, xml nodes for the grid/listing). Have a look at the code below.

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace Back\Hand\Model;

class TestItem extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel\TestItem');
    }
}
```

**ResourceModel:**

```
<?php

namespace Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel;

class TestItem extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('test_entity', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

**Collection:**

```
<?php

namespace Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel\TestItem;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Back\Hand\Model\TestItem', 'Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel\TestItem');
        $this->_map['fields']['entity_id'] = 'main_table.id';
    }

}
```

**Grid:**

```
<?php

namespace Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel\TestItem\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface as SearchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel\TestItem\Collection as TestItemCollection;

class Collection extends TestItemCollection implements SearchInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entity,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetch,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $event,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entity,
            $logger,
            $fetch,
            $event,
            $storeManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->_aggregations;
    }

    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->_aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    public function getAllIds($limitCount = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limitCount, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="so_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel\TestItem\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel\TestItem\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">test_entity</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">testItem_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">testItem_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Back\Hand\Model\ResourceModel\TestItem</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

**so_grid.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">listing_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Page</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="so_grid_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">so_grid_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">so_grid</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns.images</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
<columns name="listing_columns">
    <column name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Probably I don't need *all* the code above to get the grid going. But still... I find all this relentless. So much stuff going around just to render a grid with data.

Comment: There is an issue with an `<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>` this code. you cna not add column if already added column in form.xml

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `<filters>` and `<paging>` in your `xml` have to be placed inside `<listingToolbar>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">listing_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Item</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <!-- Data Source -->
    <dataSource name="so_grid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">TestDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">so_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">request_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <!-- Filters -->
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <!-- Paging -->
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </listingToolbar>
    <!-- Columns -->
    <columns name="listing_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">so_grid.so_grid.listing_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: It didn't work. But you're right about the order. I've updated my question with more information. Not sure if it'll help. I keep wondering whether I've setup the `DataSource` wrong or it's just something in the xml.